# SearchResultCollection: looping through each record is very slow

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am facing a strange problem from last 4-5 days. Earlier its was working perfectly fine.

I am running an LDAP query that returns SearchResultCollection (Muliple entries) as below:

```
using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
{
   searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName"); 
   searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
   searcher.PageSize = limit;
   searcher.Sort = new SortOption("sAMAccountName", SortDirection.Ascending);
   var result = searcher.FindAll();
 }
```

Then I am iterating over the SearchResultCollection as below:

```
foreach (SearchResult r in result)
{
.....
}
```

But the above loop is very slow. Also, I can't even debug and watch the result, its trowing error.

The same was working fine couple of days ago.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: How many items are you going to find? Can you try without setting the `Sort` property?

Comment: Min 1 and Max 50.  I tried removing sort, but result is same.

Comment: Try playing with the `SearchScope` and `Filter` properties of the `searcher` object.  And try setting a low value for `PageSize`.  Finally, don't forget to call `Dispose()` on `entry`.

Comment: @TawabWakil: The same was working couple of days ago. No source code change has been done since years. Its maybe due to Network/AD Issue? any thoughts?

Comment: We don't always have control over the network/AD.  Maybe it's not a code issue, but maybe you can still fix it with code.